# Dygraphs - Legend disappears when Zoom is in progress

Tags: legend, dygraphs

When I do a horizontal zoom on the Graph, Legend disappears and comes back when the zoomed graph is loaded.

Screenshots:
[image]

Do we have any option to make the Legend static/ appear even when a Zoom is in process internally instead of disappear/appear between zoom operations.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting [`hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#hideOverlayOnMouseOut%60) or [`legend: "always"`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#legend).